# Mount filesystem over sshfs at system startup / boot Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: macos, ssh, macos-mojave, sshfs, mounted-volumes

I have an account at rsync.net.
I have now mounted this filesystem using sshfs.  The rsync.net account now show in the finder, and I am able to drag and drop using finder.

Mojave 10.14.6

Now, I want mount the rsync.net filesystem over sshfs at boot / system startup. How can this be done ?  If it is difficult to mount at boot, automount when logging in is also acceptable.

Below is some output of various commands, for a better understanding of the system.

> Tormods-MacBook-Pro:~ tormod$ sshfs  --version
>
> SSHFS version 2.5 (OSXFUSE SSHFS 2.5.0) OSXFUSE 3.10.3 FUSE library
> version: 2.9.7 fuse: no mount point Tormods-MacBook-Pro:~ tormod$
>
> Tormods-MacBook-Pro:~ tormod$ kextstat|grep fuse  185    0
> 0xffffff7f85a93000 0x19000    0x19000
> com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfuse (3.10.3)
> AF3874A9-CF4E-39BF-A807-F61D1E6FABBF <8 6 5 3 1>
> Tormods-MacBook-Pro:~tormod$

Answer (score 0):

I will give an update on the matter.

Script is named : startup.sh
contents of script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Load modules for Fuse
/Library/Filesystems/osxfuse.fs/Contents/Resources/load_osxfuse
/usr/sbin/sysctl -w vfs.generic.osxfuse.tunables.allow_other=1
#Connect to rsync_net
/usr/local/bin/sshfs XXXX@prio.ch-s011.rsync.net: /mnt/sshfs -oauto_cache,reconnect,local,volname=rsync_net,allow_other,defer_permissions
```

Regardless, I am able to run the script by terminal, but ONLY if I give this command in terminal :

```
Tormods-MacBook-Pro:Scripts tormod$ sudo bash startup.sh
Password:
vfs.generic.osxfuse.tunables.allow_other: 1 -> 1
Tormods-MacBook-Pro:Scripts tormod$
```

It is impossible to run the script by typing name of script, and enter.
So, some things is working and some things is not working.......
Any help appreciated !

Update :

I have looked in a Launchd tutorial :
https://medium.com/@chetcorcos/a-simple-launchd-tutorial-9fecfcf2dbb3

This is the error codes I get when I try to run :

```
Tormods-MacBook-Pro:LaunchDaemons tormod$ launchctl load com.startup.plist
```

Error codes from Console.app :

```
Sep  5 21:08:08 Tormods-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100009.Aqua): com.startup (lint): UserName is not supported for non-System services.
Sep  5 21:08:08 Tormods-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.100009.Aqua): com.startup (lint): GroupName is not supported for non-System services.
Sep  5 21:08:08 Tormods-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.startup[680]): Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 2: No such file or directory: /usr/bin/env bash /Users/root/Scripts/startup.sh
Sep  5 21:08:08 Tormods-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.startup[680]): Service setup event to handle failure and will not launch until it fires.
Sep  5 21:08:08 Tormods-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.startup[680]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
```

I think the problem is maybe in the chmod properties of directories, files or commands.

I belive the script will run as root user.  So, what ownership / chmod should the directories where the script is located have ?

What ownership / chmod should the the script file have ?

I see there are several attributes for the osxfuse.
I find the different attributes here :

https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Mount-options

Now, I run : allow_other

Comment: Do you have a user called `admin`? Can you login as that user?

Comment: I have a user called root, I can login as root.  I do not have a user called admin.  I have a user with admin rights.

Comment: I think the problem is maybe in the chmod properties of directories, files or commands.

I belive the script will run as root user.  So, what ownership / chmod should the directories where the script is located have ?

What ownership / chmod should the the script file have ?



I see there are several attributes for the osxfuse.

I find the different attributes here :

https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Mount-options

Now, I run : allow_other



The correct way is maybe : allow_root ?

Comment: Why do you have this then? `  <key>UserName</key> <string>admin</string>`

Comment: Good question !  What do you you suggest I change it to ?

Comment: I guess I’d remove it... along with the following `usergroup`

Comment: I removed the <key>UserName</key> <string>admin</string>,  I also checked chmod for the directories and script file.  Still no go.   When I run the script, I suppose the wireless connection of the macbook is NOT active.   The internet connection is active after login. Is it possible to add a delay in the script, so that the sshfs connection is up after the wifi connection is ok ?

Answer (score 0):

New  "com.startup.plist" file.
Now the file will load and run at boot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.startup</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/bash</string>
        <string>/Library/Scripts/Startup/startup.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.startup.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.startup.stdout</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now the LaunchDaemons  startup file run..
On this system, I have also configured Apple's automount.
My list of mounts :

```
bash-5.0# compgen -c | grep ^mount
mount_sshfs
mount_hfs
mount_apfs
mount_udf
mount_cd9660
mount_sshfs
mount_exfat
mount_webdav
mount_msdos
mount_9p
mount_ntfs
mount_nfs
mount_ftp
mount
mount_afp
mount_smbfs
mount_cddafs
mount_fdesc
mount_acfs
mount_devfs
bash-5.0#
```

Now, everything works when I have SIP disabled.
The sshfs connection to rsync.net is up, an is connected at boot / startup.
The setting I used for  the mount point:

```
/mnt/sshfs
```

This was needed in order  for automount and the mounting at boot to be able to work together.

New contents of the "/etc/auto_master"

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master       # Use directory service
/net               -hosts       -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home              auto_home    -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers   -fstab
/-                 -static
/mnt/sshfs         auto_sshfs   -nobrowse,nosuid
```

In finder the disk, or the remote sshfs connection is called rsync_net, because of the

```
volname=rsync_net
```

setting for the sshfs connection.

So, now everything is good until I turn on the SIP, when this is turned on, the the fuse will no longer load at all.

output of

```
kextstat|grep fuse
```

No output with SIP enabled.
In other words, when SIP is enabled the modules for fuse is NOT loaded in the kernel.....
I am hoping there is a fix i can do, as I would prefer to run the OS with SIP enabled.